# Evaluating the limit $\lim_{x\to0}{\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+cx}}{x}\right)}$

Tags: limits

In trying to evaluate the following limit:
$$\large\lim_{x\to0}{\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+cx}}{x}\right)}$$

Which gives the indefinite form of:

$$\large\frac{1}{0}$$

What would be the best solution to evaluating this limit?

Comment: look the side limits.

Comment: Wouldn't that give me infinity values?

Comment: Actually $\infty$ and $-\infty$ make sense.

Comment: But is there no way to transform the equation so I get a real number?

Comment: Is an _actual value_ real number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Look the side limits:

$$\frac{1}{0^+}=\infty$$

$$\frac{1}{0^-}=-\infty$$

Comment: Yes but us there no way to transform the equation to I can get an actual value?

Comment: I think he's trying to say the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @OmariCelestine: what do you conclude when you get different side limits?

Comment: That there is no limit.

Comment: @OmariCelestine: correct!